# Securing Access to User Balances in Ethereum Smart Contract

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, balances, secure-signer

I'm working on a Mobile app where users sign up, and they are assigned public and private keys. However, these keys are never actually shared with the users but are stored in the database. I want to ensure that only the Go backend, which is the only entity that knows both the public and private keys of each user, can access and retrieve their balances from an Ethereum smart contract written in solidity.

Here's the current setup:

- Users sign up, and public and private keys are generated and stored in the database.
- The Go backend is the only entity that has access to both the public and private keys.
- The backend call the Ethereum smart contract to fetch the user's balance.

Right now the GetMyBalance method is like this

```
function getMyBalance() external view returns (uint256) {
    return balances[msg.sender];
}
```

But, correct me if I am wrong, anybody who knows my public key and the contract address could find out my balance right?

My question is: How can I modify the GetMyBalance to ensure that only the Go backend can access user balances while ensuring other users or unauthorized entities cannot access this data, and how should I call the method from Go?

Another question, In the first place, Is the approach of having the Go backend as the sole entity knowing both keys a valid and secure method for controlling access to user balances?

Thanks for any advices

Comment: Everything on the blockchain is public, so you can't hide a balance that is stored on the blockchain. It should be possible if they are stored off-chain.

Comment: @Ismael, thanks for your clarification but let's say my balances stored like this:
 
`mapping(address => uint256) public balances` 



and a method :



`function logWork(uint256 _hours) external {
        uint256 coins = _hours * 1000;
        balances[msg.sender] += coins;
   }`



How can i make so that only my backend that has both pubKey and privKey can actually call the method and increase my balance ?



I asked ChatGPT and it says to sign the transaction and then use **ecrecover**.
Would you recommend doing so? and If yes you have some examples/resources/link ?

Comment: Basically: the msg.sender value can be changed by the caller of a function to impersonate another address when sending a transaction. So i want a specific user can only update their own balance and not manipulate others' balances, so chat GPT suggest to implement a mechanism to manually verify the authenticity of the caller's action. One common approach is to use digital signatures, as mentioned earlier, to ensure that the sender has the private key for the address they are trying to update. Is this industry standards?

Comment: Everything on the blockchain is public. It could be difficult to access, but anyone will be able to read it. In particular using signatures will be more difficult, but anyone could read the values. To make changes limited to some address you could use something like [OpenZepplin's AccessControl](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/5.x/access-control). If you have more doubts it will be better to create a new question.

Comment: @Ismael Agree, I will create new question. 

Thank you for your help, i am new to the blockchain world and i have not mentor (apart from ChatGPT, which however is not updated on the matter) so I fall into these loopholes of questions. 

Btw I cannot believe how there is no ERC for a coin that include built-in mechanisms for minting tokens only if the caller can sign a message.